# How to use web.config [IIS] to shorten a URL GET data

Tags: php, iis

I've tried looking around, but can't seem to exactly find the words to my query. I do not have the sufficient knowledge to do this on my own, but basically I want to shorten this URL:

```
http://example.com/register/?ref=Liam
```

to

```
http://example.com/register/ref/Liam
```

Using IIS web.config.

Answer (score 0):

you ca use this web.config:

```
<rule name="rule 1N" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^register/(.+)/(.*)$"  />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="/register/?{R:1}={R:2}"  />
</rule>
```

Now if you open `example.com/register/ref/r` You see `example.com/register?ref=r`

Comment: I don't want it to change it to register.php?ref, I want it staying as register/ref/

Comment: Changed answer to register/ref .